# FTPSClient retrievefile() hanging

Tags: java, apache, ftp, ftp-client, ftps

I'm creating an apache FTPS client (because the remote server won't allow plain FTP). I can connect and delete files without problem, but when using retrieveFile() or retrieveFileStream(), it hangs.

For some reason, very small files do transfer (up to 5792 bytes), but anything else gives the following PrintCommandListener output:

> run:
>   220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
>   220-You are user number 2 of 50 allowed.
>   220-Local time is now 19:42. Server port: 21.
>   220-This is a private system - No anonymous login
>   220-IPv6 connections are also welcome on this server.
>   220 You will be disconnected after 15 minutes of inactivity.
>   AUTH TLS
>   234 AUTH TLS OK.
>   USER 
>   331 User  OK. Password required
>   PASS 
>   230 OK. Current restricted directory is /
>   TYPE A
>   200 TYPE is now ASCII
>   EPSV
>   229 Extended Passive mode OK (|||53360|)
>   RETR test.txt
>   150-Accepted data connection
>   150 7.3 kbytes to download

Here is the code:

```
try {

    FTPSClient ftpClient = new FTPSClient("tls",false);

    ftpClient.addProtocolCommandListener(new PrintCommandListener(new  PrintWriter(System.out)));

    ftpClient.connect(host, port);

    int reply = ftpClient.getReplyCode();

    if (FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)) {
        ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        ftpClient.login(username, password);
        ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(tempfile);
        ftpClient.setFileType(FTPClient.ASCII_FILE_TYPE);
        ftpClient.retrieveFile("test.txt", outputStream);
        outputStream.close();
        ftpClient.logout();
        ftpClient.disconnect();
    }
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    System.out.println("FTP client received network error");
}
```

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please format your code properly. You can just mark it and point-and-click format with the tools provided on top of the editor.

Answer (score 1):

Hope someone finds my comment useful after several years.
In my case, I replaced `retrieveFile` with `retrieveFileStream`. It requires more code, but at least it works.

Answer (score 0):

Typically the FTP command sequence for FTPS connections goes (per [RFC 4217](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4217#section-9)) `AUTH TLS`, `PBSZ 0`, *then* `USER`, `PASS`, *etc*.  Thus you might try:

```
FTPSClient ftpClient = new FTPSClient("tls",false);
ftpClient.addProtocolCommandListener(new PrintCommandListener(new PrintWriter(System.out)));
ftpClient.connect(host, port);
int reply = ftpClient.getReplyCode();
if (FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)) {
    ftpClient.execPBSZ(0);
    reply = ftpClient.getReplyCode();
    // Check for PBSZ error responses...
    ftpClient.execPROT("P");
    reply = ftpClient.getReplyCode();
    // Check for PROT error responses...

    ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
```

This *explictly* tells the server to *not* buffer the data connection (`PBSZ 0`), and to use TLS for protecting the data transfer (`PROT P`).

The fact that you *are* able to transfer some bytes indicates that the issue is **not** the usual complication with firewalls/routers/NAT, which is another common FTPS issue.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, that is useful because I was half expecting it to be a firewall thing. But that code doesn't work, prevents hanging but outputs "FTP client received network error".

Comment: Hmm.  I wonder if `FTPSClient` doesn't expect protected data transfers.  What happens if you use `execPROT("C")` instead?  This tells the server to _clear_ the data transfer channel of protection (just for testing).

Comment: You might also double-check that the server (and any firewalls/NATs/routers) are behaving properly by using `lftp` (or some other FTPS client) to download a file.  If _that_ succeeds, then you know that it's a matter of finding the right code; if not, then the issue might not be in your code, but elsewhere.

Comment: It's hanging again, with execPROT("C"). I can download server files with filezilla (explorer times out). Will look into lftp, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Even if `PBSZ 0` and `PROT P` are called in the correct sequence, sometimes the server does require SSL session reuse which is not the case by default for the client.

For example, the following reply comes when trying to list a directory. As a result no content listing is returned, this way the client seeing as if the directory is empty:

```
LIST /
150 Here comes the directory listing.
522 SSL connection failed; session reuse required: see require_ssl_reuse option in sftpd.conf man page
```

To overcome that, custom initialization of the FTPSClient is needed by overriding `_prepareDataSocket_()` method.

The solution is explained in details here: https://eng.wealthfront.com/2016/06/10/connecting-to-an-ftps-server-with-ssl-session-reuse-in-java-7-and-8/

Working code sample taken from the above link:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Locale;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSessionContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;

import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPSClient;

import com.google.common.base.Throwables;

public class SSLSessionReuseFTPSClient extends FTPSClient {

  // adapted from: https://trac.cyberduck.io/changeset/10760
  @Override
  protected void _prepareDataSocket_(final Socket socket) throws IOException {
    if(socket instanceof SSLSocket) {
      final SSLSession session = ((SSLSocket) _socket_).getSession();
      final SSLSessionContext context = session.getSessionContext();
      try {
        final Field sessionHostPortCache = context.getClass().getDeclaredField("sessionHostPortCache");
        sessionHostPortCache.setAccessible(true);
        final Object cache = sessionHostPortCache.get(context);
        final Method putMethod = cache.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("put",Object.class, Object.class);
        putMethod.setAccessible(true);
        final Method getHostMethod = socket.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getHost");
        getHostMethod.setAccessible(true);
        Object host = getHostMethod.invoke(socket);
        final String key = String.format("%s:%s", host, String.valueOf(socket.getPort())).toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT);
        putMethod.invoke(cache, key, session);
      } catch(Exception e) {
        throw Throwables.propagate(e);
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @MattKe Thanks, posted the working code sample here.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I fixed the problem after upgrading Apache Commons Net to 3.8.0.

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'commons-net:commons-net:3.8.0'
    ...
}
```